# How to copy a text/plain file from Google Drive to Android App local File

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I can download the file but I can't copy it's contents.

I'm using this code:

```
HttpResponse resp = gDrive.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(driveFile.getDownloadUrl())).execute();
InputStream in= resp.getContent();
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
while(in.available()>0) {
    fos.write(in.read());
}
```

But the in.available() returns always 0. And yes, the content is there. If I just use in.read(), the first character comes ok.

The files are really small, just a few bytes or even empty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `available()`. It is explicitly noted in the documentation that `available()` will only tell you how many bytes *definitely* are available, but that it may return 0 if it feels like it.

You want to use [`read(byte[])`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) to read chunks of undefined size into a buffer until it returns -1, and the write the corresponding amount of bytes out using [`write(byte[], int, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) - something like this:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
while (true) {
    int bytes = in.read(buf);
    if (bytes < 0) break;
    fos.write(buf, 0, bytes);
}
```

The Guava library [provides a function for that](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29).